# Is there a way to return the value in a condition in a ternary expression without re-specifying it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements, dry, conditional-operator

Is there a way to execute the following code, without specifying 'a' twice?

`const result = a > b ? a : default;`

Useful for when the ternary is inside an arrow function and 'a' is an arithmetic operation the uses the function parameters:

`someFunc((value) => value + otherValue / 10 > b ? value + otherValue / 10 : default)`

Remember that 'a' can be a highly complex calculated expression.

The only way I know to write `value + otherValue / 10` once is as follows:

```
someFunc((value) => {
  const result = value + otherValue / 10;
  return result > b ? result : default;
});
```

I'm looking for something like:
`const result = a ?? > b : default;`

PS. I know there's nothing wrong with the last example, just asking to figure out if JavaScript has a better way of doing this.

Comment: What's wrong with the latter example? You don't have to minify your developement code, a minifier will do it for you when you're moving the code to the production.

Comment: Use an IIFE, something like: `result = ( value => condition(value) ? value : defaultValue )(<expression>)`. Although, that's easily extractable to a generic function, so you don't even have to have it inline. In which case you don't have much need for shorter syntax.

Comment: Stop worrying about how many character your code takes. Worry about whether people who have to maintain your code later will understand it.

Comment: @Teemu Nothing wrong with the latter example. But you can say the same thing about the ternary operation as well.

Comment: What ever else you put in that ternary, it only obscures your intention. Like Heretic Monkey said, readability is the number one to concern when you're writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such functionality in JavaScript. You can do this if you need to check the truthiness of the variable. For example `a || default` so if a is truthy it will be returned otherwise `default`. But in your case you need to make a comparison of `a > b` and for the you can only use Ternary expression with re-specifying `a`.

Comment: I understand. But that's a bad practice in case 'a' is a complex calculated expression.

Comment: Well if `a` is a complex value then you definitely don't want to do it in one line, this will be unreadable

Comment: Not necessarily, `a` can invoke a function.